# Should my air conditioner be running its air directly through internal spaces?

Tags: hvac, ceiling, ducts, central-air, air-quality

##### Should a newly installed “ducted” split system be running its intake air directly through internal spaces, or should I demand that the system be sealed so that it only draws air from living spaces?

I’ve moved into a new development with a “ducted” split-system A/C (installed in a ductless configuration, with everything set up behind the one grille):

[image: Combined A/C supply, A/C return, and apparently “ceiling cavity air” grille]

A small portion of the grille is dedicated to supply of heated/cooled air; the remaining majority is used for retrieving the air to heat/cool.

I needed to clean the filters, which required me to get into the access hatch (pictured to the right of the cabinets).

In doing so, I found that the air intake is in no way sealed to the grille—instead, it simply sucks air directly from within the ceiling cavity:

[image: Internal view of grille from top, within ceiling cavity]

The builder has informed me that this is a “typical” installation.  Nonetheless, I have several concerns:

- This seems to be inviting moisture and other contaminants (like airborne cooking grease) into the hollows of the walls.
- This seems to be inviting impurities from the ceiling cavity (like insulation and plaster dust) into the living space.  (Indeed, the filter was covered with plaster dust.)
- None of this seems intuitively healthy for the A/C or for the occupants of the space: plaster dust, for one, contains crystalline silica—which is known to cause lung cancer over time, among other ailments.
- The insulation I had to move in order to access the filters was incredibly dusty, suggesting that it had itself been functioning as an air filter.

###### Questions

- Is this really a usual way of setting up a “ducted” split system?
- Is it safe: will it increase e.g. the risks of mold?
- Is it likely to cause damage and increase repair costs over time?
- Are there any known construction codes (especially ones applicable to Australia) that permit or prohibit this sort of setup?
- Should I be flagging this as a defective/incomplete/unsafe installation?

Comment: That grill should be sealed to the conditioned air and separated from the return air, (that should also be sealed and filtered.)  That is a bad job.

Comment: Often times, an empty joist bay is used as a return duct without any sort of piping or insulating board. Don't know if this is still to code or not. If it's not, then no, yours shouldn't have been installed that way.

Comment: Thank you, @manassehkatz: the filters are indeed in the air handler, which is behind roughly the middle of the grille as pictured.  One side mystery solved!

Comment: From the photo, it doesn't look like there's any room to remove that filter. Can you remove it?

Comment: Thankfully, yes: it removes just fine once the insulation is temporarily removed from the cavity.

Comment: I’ve now removed the parts from my post about trying to locate the filter, so that it can focus on the key issue of air being routed into and out of the cavity and surrounds.

Comment: In most of the houses I've seen and lived in (USA, Midwest), the air returns are often at least partly utilizing wall cavities or joist cavities.  The supply air is usually in ducts (insulated or not, depending on what spaces they're running through before getting to the registers).  So I guess I'd answer that return ducts probably *should* be run through sealed ductwork back to your air handler, but for practical purposes that's often not done, whether due to incompetence, laziness, or ease of installation.